# Linux: how to replace all instances of a string with another in all files of a single type

Tags: linux, replace, sed, find

I want to replace for example all instances of "123" with "321" contained within all .txt files in a folder (recursively).
I thought of doing this

```
sed -i 's/123/321/g' | find . -name \*.txt
```

but before possibly screwing all my files I would like to ask if it will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the `sed` and the `find` back to front.  With GNU `sed` and the `-i` option, you could use:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sed -i s/123/321/g {} +
```

The `find` finds files with extension `.txt` and runs the `sed -i` command on groups of them (that's the `+` at the end; it's standard in POSIX 2008, but not all versions of `find` necessarily support it).  In this example substitution, there's no danger of misinterpretation of the `s/123/321/g` command so I've not enclosed it in quotes.  However, for simplicity and general safety, it is probably better to enclose the `sed` script in single quotes whenever possible.

You could also use `xargs` (and again using GNU extensions `-print0` to `find` and `-0` and `-r` to `xargs`):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r sed -i 's/123/321/g'
```

The `-r` means 'do not run if there are no arguments' (so the `find` doesn't find anything).  The `-print0` and `-0` work in tandem, generating file names ending with the C null byte `'\0'` instead of a newline, and avoiding misinterpretation of file names containing newlines, blanks and so on.

Note that before running the script on the real data, you can and should test it.  Make a dummy directory (I usually call it `junk`), copy some sample files into the junk directory, change directory into the junk directory, and test your script on those files.  Since they're copies, there's no harm done if something goes wrong.  And you can simply remove everything in the directory afterwards: `rm -fr junk` should never cause you anguish.

Comment: Thanks. That worked just fine with a little tweak: you forgot the quotes
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sed -i 's/123/321/g {}' +

Comment: Interesting; were I to be asked, I'd have said that the quotes you show would break it, rather than fix it.  But who am I to argue with the empirical evidence...